# latin characters showing in some parts of the page and not others

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding, latin

the page in question is  [Apple Amor](http://www.appleamor.com/test/)

You can see that in the footer the spanish vowels seem to be showing properly , but in the slide down bar(header) they get messed up.

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 3):

Your page is encoded in `ISO-8859-1`. Wherever that header comes from, it is most likely encoded in `UTF-8`.

You would have to change the character set of your page to `UTF-8` (that would probably have some consequences) or convert the incoming data from the header. I don't know where it's coming from, so it's hard to tell what the right method would be.

Mandatory basic reading on the issue: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: i just noticed that when the page shows html content such as <div id="spanishblah">asdas</div> .. the characters get messed up. On the other hand if i use jquery innerhtml or php echo they come out fine

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your page source shows that you're using:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Note that the above tag is not well formed. Where is its closing character "/"? Content-Type should be between double quotes.

Add this tag to your page and test:

```
<html lang="es">
```

If that doesn't solve your problem try to change the charset tag to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: But that will break any non-ASCII characters he has on the rest of his page, won't it? He can't just switch to another character set without changing the content. But good points otherwise

Comment: tried both .. did not work.. but i just noticed that when the page shows html content such as <div id="spanishblah">asdas</div> .. the characters get messed up.

On the other hand if i use jquery innerhtml or php echo they come out fine .